# C++ overload the stream I/O operators when reading from a txt file

Tags: c++, io

I have a text file full of information about books for a library simulation program, here's a sample:

```
P.G. Wodehouse, "Heavy Weather" (336 pp.) [PH.409 AVAILABLE FOR LENDING]
Isaac Asimov, "The Gods Themselves" (288 pp.) [UM.824 AVAILABLE FOR LENDING]
Olaf Stapledon, "Odd John" (224 pp.) [LN.171 AVAILABLE FOR LENDING]
...etc
```

I'm new to C++ and I've written this as a start but as you can see there's no clear separation between each piece of data I need and I can't figure out how to easily separate them, please help:

```
istream& operator<<(istream& in, LibraryBook& b){
    string author,title,classification,status;
    int pages;
    in >> author >> title >> pages >> classification >> status;
    return in;
}
```

Comment: It should probably be `operator>>`... `>>` is for `istream`, `<<` is for `ostream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. It uses [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), [`std::istream::ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) and [`std::istream::operator>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/).

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, LibraryBook& b){
    // Read author name until ',':
    std::getline(in, b.author, ',');
    // Ignore the space and the quotation mark:
    in.ignore(2);
    // Read title until quotation mark:
    std::getline(in, b.title, '"');
    // Ignore the space and the left bracket:
    in.ignore(2);
    // Read the page amount:
    in >> b.pages;
    // Ignore " pp.) [":
    in.ignore(7);
    // Read the classification:
    in >> b.classification;
    // Ignore the space:
    in.ignore(1);
    // Read status until ']':
    std::getline(in, b.status, ']');
    // Ignore the last newline character:
    in.ignore(1);
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could do that with getline and I didn't know ignore was a thing

Answer (score 2):

I would use `getline` and then the string functions to extract the fields:

```
string str;
getline(in, str);

string::size_type k1, k2;

k1 = 0;
k2 = str.find(',');
string author = str.substr(k1, k2);

k1 = str.find('"');
k2 = str.find('"', k1);
string title = str.substr(k1, k2);

k1 = str.find('(');
k2 = str.find(' ', k1);
string temp = str.substr(k1+1, k2-k1);
int pages = atoi(temp.c_str());
...
```

Comment: No need for `temp`, `c_str` and `atoi`. There's [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol): `int pages = stoi(str.substr(...))`